# const = BASE_PATH.'/folder' не работает на сервере

Tags: php, классы, path, const

Здравствуйте. Мой код такой:

В index.php

```
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../'));
```

В классе Config.php:

```
class Config {
   const ERROR_PATH = BASE_PATH.'/runtime/errors';
}
```

В локале все работает. А в сервере ошибка:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/xxx/xxx/Core/Config.php on line 106
```

Как я могу это исправить ?

Comment: убедиться, что версия пхп 5.6 и выше?

Comment: php version 5.6. В локале тоже 5.6